# Why does this return an invalid date with moment js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

This

```
moment(1420066800000);
```

returns a moment object with an invalid date, why?

**EDIT**:

```
moment(1420066800000).isValid()
```

returns true! But: the moments' property

```
_d.__proto__
```

is an "Invalid Date" object. That's what confused my, since I thought this was causing wrong behaviour in my application.

Comment: that's pretty cool. both `1420066800001` and `1420066799999` *do* produce valid dates

Comment: What timezone are you in? It works here.

Comment: GMT+1 seems to be a problem.

Comment: Okay moment(1420066800000).isValid() returns true. I got confused, by looking into the object, as it has a __proto__ of Invalid Date. This also is answered here: https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/1015#issuecomment-22950634

Comment: This seems to be how behaves momentjs in its internal date management and should not be a problem to handle moment dates. However there might be some internal Javascript Date management that make days at millisecond `0` invalid

Comment: how to remake the bug for other people?

Comment: @Felix: All Date objects inherit from the Date prototype which does not have any timestamp - and is therefore invalid

Answer (score -1):

What is wrong with Wed Dec 31 2014 23:00:00 GMT+0000 (UTC) ?

```
> d = moment(1420066800000);
{ _isAMomentObject: true,
  _i: 1420066800000,
  _f: undefined,
  _l: undefined,
  _strict: undefined,
  _isUTC: false,
  _pf: 
  { empty: false,
    unusedTokens: [],
    unusedInput: [],
    overflow: -2,
    charsLeftOver: 0,
    nullInput: false,
    invalidMonth: null,
    invalidFormat: false,
    userInvalidated: false,
    iso: false },
  _d: Wed Dec 31 2014 23:00:00 GMT+0000 (UTC) }
```

Comment: it looks like it is dependent of time zone then, since it produces this : `_d: Thu Jan 01 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (W. Europe Standard Time)__proto__: Invalid Date` for me

Comment: This question is not an answer